# C api for sending wifi frames

Tags: networking, c, wireless

Is there a C library/api that allows me to send arbitrary wireless frames? Assuming I have some binary struct/blob which is a well-formed RTS control frame, for example: how can I send that to some other IP or MAC on my lan?

I am aware of tools like air*-ng which appear to generate and send packets from my wireless card, but I am looking for a library.

Does the driver for my card expose any functions? Or am I (likely) not understanding what drivers do. Or perhaps there is some linux system call that I can make?